# Syntax error when inserting to MySQL table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, sql-insert

I'm getting a syntax error when trying to insert into a MySQL table using PHP. I send a POST request from node.js to that page and it should process it and send it to the database, but it just throws a syntax error (1064). I am new in here, so I don't know what else should I put in here, but I am happy to provide any more information that I have.

```
<head>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
//Define the variables and set to empty values
$steam = $load = $weight = $source_city = $destination_city = $trailer_damage = $income = $distance = $fuel = $collisions = $speeding = "";
//Set them to the values of the request
$steam = $_POST["steam"];
$load = $_POST["load"];
$weight = $_POST["weight"];
$source_city = $_POST["source_city"];
$destination_city = $_POST["destination_city"];
$trailer_damage = $_POST["trailer_damage"];
$income = $_POST["income"];
$distance = $_POST["distance"];
$fuel = $_POST["fuel"];
$collisions = $_POST["collisions"];
$speeding = $_POST["speeding"];
?>
<h2> Just for submitting the data to the MySQL!
Don't do anything with this page! </h2>

<?php
//Define the connection configuration and the datalist
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "hello";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO MyTable (steam, load, weight, source_city, destination_city, trailer_damage, income, distance, fuel, collisions, speeding)
VALUES ($steam, $load, $weight, $source_city, $destination_city, $trailer_damage, $income, $distance, $fuel, $collisions, $speeding)';

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Here is the error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2> Just for submitting the data to the API from the tracker
Don't do anything with this page! </h2>

Error: INSERT INTO MyTable (steam, load, weight, source_city, destination_city, trailer_damage, income, distance, fuel, collisions, speeding)
VALUES (test, test, 15.4, test, test, 80.59, 8126418, 48197, 20.14, 5, 5)<br>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'load, weight, source_city, destination_city, trailer_damage, income, distance, f' at line 1

G:\Docs\FT\tracker>node debug.js
G:\Docs\FT\tracker\debug.js:21
                if (err) throw err;
                         ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (Path\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:411:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:422:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (Path\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (Path\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (Path\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:118:18)
    at Connection._implyConnect (Path\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:453:10)
    at Connection.query (Path\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Path\debug.js:18:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
```

Also sorry for just basic editing of the code, but I am not sure what to edit and what not, so I included it as original as possible ;) Thanks for your help.

Comment: VARCHAR columns need to be surrounded by quote `'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that "load" is a keyword. To have your column use keyword as its name, you have to surround it in backticks `keyword`. It is generally better to do it always.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (`something`, `load`) VALUES ("a", "b")
```

Here is list of keywords for MySQL 5.6:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html